# TYPO3 v9.5.11 Extbase: Inject ServiceObject generated by a ContainerClass into Repository

Tags: php, dependency-injection, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I am trying to inject an service object into my Repository. I have created different Service Classes under the directory Classes/Services. There is also one class that I created called ContainerService, which creates and instantiate one ServiceObject for each Service Class.

ContainerService Class:

```
namespace VendorName\MyExt\Service;

use VendorName\MyExt\Service\RestClientService;

class ContainerService {

    private $restClient;     
    private $otherService;

    /**
     * @return RestClientService
     */
    public function getRestClient() {

        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager::class);

        if ($this->restClient === null) {
            $this->restClient = $objectManager->get(RestClientService::class);            
        }

        return $this->restClient;
    }
...
```

As I said, I create my ServiceObjects in the ContainerService Class.
Now I want to inject the ContainerService into my Repository and use it.

MyRepository Class:

```
namespace VendorName\MyExt\Domain\Repository;

use VendorName\MyExt\Service\ContainerService;

class MyRepository extends Repository
{    
    /**
     * @var ContainerService
     */
    public $containerService;

    /**
     * inject the ContainerService
     *     
     * @param ContainerService $containerService 
     * @return void
     */
    public function injectContainerService(ContainerService $containerService) {
        $this->containerService = $containerService;
    }

    // Use Objects from The ContainerService

    public function findAddress($addressId) {
        $url = 'Person/getAddressbyId/' 
        $someData = $this->containerService->getRestClient()->sendRequest($url)
    return $someData;
    }
```

In MyController I recieve the $someData from my findAddress function and do some work with it.

But when I call my Page, I get following ErrorMessage:

```
(1/2) #1278450972 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\Exception\UnknownClassException

Class ContainerService does not exist. Reflection failed.
```

Already tried to reload all Caches and dumping the Autoload didn't help either.
Didn't install TYPO3 with composer.
I appreciate any advice or help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the Issue.
In MyRepository Class there was a Problem with the Annotations and the TypeHint:

```
namespace VendorName\MyExt\Domain\Repository;

use VendorName\MyExt\Service\ContainerService;

class MyRepository extends Repository
{    
    /**
     *** @var \VendorName\MyExt\Service\ContainerService**
     */
    public $containerService;

    /**
     * inject the ContainerService
     *     
     * @param \VendorName\MyExt\Service\ContainerService $containerService 
     * @return void
     */
    public function injectContainerService(\VendorName\MyExt\Service\ContainerService $containerService) {
        $this->containerService = $containerService;
    }

    // Use Objects from The ContainerService

    public function findAddress($addressId) {
        $url = 'Person/getAddressbyId/' 
        $someData = $this->containerService->getRestClient()->sendRequest($url)
    return $someData;
    }
```

Now it works.